# pentium t2390 dual core 3gb ram just installed 12.04, should I change to 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

had a 12.04 disk and installed on a vista laptop for a friend, did not realize till install that 14.04LTS was available. should I burn a disk and reinstall 14.04, upgrade or stick with 12.04?

Comment: if it is not broken don't fix it. nothing wrong with 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I agree if it's not broke don't fix it since that release has 5 years support. If there is a feature on 14.04 that is being eyeballed or just want most up to date then do the following command after making a backup if feels necessary even.

sudo update-manager -d

Comment: this is a fresh install, tonight, changing from vista. I do not have an eye on any features, but wouldn't mind most up to date. more concerned how 14.04 will work with this older laptop's resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Upgrading to newer version because 14.04 is too good than 12.04. A number of tweaks added to Unity desktop in 14.04. I found 14.04 more solid than previous LTS release for myself.

Answer (score -2):

No need to burn a disk, if you want to upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

updates and upgrade option will be available system setting if you don't want to go through the terminal.

or:

```
 sudo do-release-upgrade
```

if you do.

Comment: Agree on: 'If it not broken, don't fix it'

Comment: I'm assuming you have an internet connection.

Comment: Yes I have an internet connection. Just thought complete install might be better than an upgrade. installed 12.04 tonight, so no programs or files to save etc.

Comment: Same here. prefer a clean install.

Comment: If you are worried about resource, maybe look at the differences between xubuntu or lubuntu instead of using unity. Kubuntu is really nice but more graphics intensive.

Comment: @pythonhunter What's the context for these commands? They won't upgrade Ubuntu from one release to another... (A 12.04 system won't become 14.04 from running those commands, which just update packages on the system that have [received patches](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).)

Comment: you are right, but the option to upgrade will become available through the software updater.